# How to configure Spring Social without Sign In Service on Page

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I would like to configure Spring Social, but the examples provide some stuff I actually don't need.
Looking at [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/blob/master/spring-social-showcase/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/showcase/config/SocialConfig.java) example there's a UserIdSource, UserConnectionRepository, ConnectController, ProviderSignInController, DisconnectController, ReconnectFilter.
I just want to use Facebooks Graph API as well as Twitters Timeline Operations to get the last tweets of a specific user. Not any Sign In services on my webpage.

My current configuration is the following:

```java
@Configuration
public class SocialConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public Facebook facebook() {
        return new FacebookTemplate(env.getProperty("facebook.accessToken"));
    }

    @Bean
    public Twitter twitter() {
        return new TwitterTemplate(env.getProperty("twitter.consumerKey"),
                env.getProperty("twitter.consumerSecret"),
                env.getProperty("twitter.accessToken"),
                env.getProperty("twitter.accessTokenSecret"));
    }
}
```

This will work for Twitter quite good but Facebook's access token is only temporary.
At first there was no access token needed when getting albums of a page.
But now we need one to get all information of a public album such as album type (sic!).

Is there any example configuring Spring Social without Sign In Service?

Answer (score 2):

First, getting the token for Facebook from the environment is not really a good idea. If what you're wanting to do is get posts for a user, the token will need to be a user token (as opposed to a more restricted application token). The way you get that token is by running the user through the authorization flow offered by Spring Social's ConnectController. This flow requires the user to *at least* sign into Facebook and authorize the application. Whether or not they sign into your application kinda depends on who the user is.

(Note that this is also true for Twitter, although Twitter access tokens don't expire. Since they don't expire, you could go about getting the access token through other means and then hard-code it in your config. That's not really how it's intended to be used, but it will work.)

The typical flow is to have the user sign into your application (either directly through some application signin page or indirectly via Facebook, Twitter, etc) and then work through the ConnectController flow to obtain authorization (and thus an access token). In the typical flow, you do not directly instantiate instances of FacebookTemplate or TwitterTemplate--they are instantiated for you via the Connection (which represents the authorization obtained by ConnectController).

To deal with expired tokens, Spring Social also offers ReconnectFilter, which attempts to reestablish a connection (by going back through ConnectController) if it detects that, for any reason, an access token is no longer valid. Although this means that the user's browser will be redirected to Facebook and back, the redirect will be unnoticed by the user as long as the authorization is still valid (tokens expire, authorizations do not). If the authorization is still valid, Facebook will redirect back without prompting the user for authorization.

If *you* are the user, then you could bypass authentication into your application, set up a UserIdSource that always returns the same ID (whatever you want it to be) and then the authorization will be associated to that ID. But you still need to go through the authorization flow to get the access token.

That said, you are welcome to obtain an access token through other means and hard-code it in your config, but as you pointed out, the token will expire and then the configuration will no longer work.

The best example I can point to is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-boot. Sure, it support authentication (both direct and provider-based), but it does demo the typical flow for obtaining a FacebookTemplate or TwitterTemplate instance which involves obtaining user authorization. You'll see that there's very little Spring Social configuration involved (actually, very little configuration of any kind involved) because it leverages Spring Boot auto-configuration. If you want a more explicit configuration example, look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase which doesn't use Spring Boot.

(IMO, you should favor using Spring Boot, though.)

Comment: It's part of my web application which shows the albums of my facebook page. I don't know why it's necessary to have an access token to get that information as it's public anyway. What's the alternative to that Jdbc stuff? I don't want to have a connection repository.

Comment: The configuration is too complicated to simply work with the Graph API.

Comment: I've used an app access token now. This allows me to do it without jdbc repository and the other objects I don't need.

Comment: So I need to build a thing, that on certain external events, posts a message to a facebook account (wall, timeline or whatever it's called these days). the account is mine. there are no other users involved. In oauth2 terms, I guess I actually need a `client_credentials` grant. Is this supported in any way? Or is that the app access token (quick google sounds like that is more for read operations).